# what is DisposableEffect and under the hood in jetpack compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, side-effects

I've been trying to understand what is DisposableEffect and How it works for a while so I have searched on the internet for this and I saw that most of the documentation are similar explanation for example

> DisposableEffect is a powerful tool provided by Jetpack Compose that
> allows you to perform side effects in your composable functions that
> need to be cleaned up when the composable leaves the composition. You
> can use keys to control when the callback function is called.

I know that DisposableEffect works asynchronously like LaunchedEffect and based on key values but when onDispose method works as you can see the definition of above

that need to be cleaned up when the composable leaves the composition

This sentence probably defines the onDispose method, so in this case, it means onDispose will work, but what does it mean **when the composable leaves the composition** is written like this everywhere? I couldn't understand.

I did it like this for example

**State**

```
data class State(
    ...
    val isError:Int?=null,
    ...
)
```

**UI**

```
val errMsg = stringResource(id = R.string.error)
val savedMsg = stringResource(id = R.string.saved)

DisposableEffect(state.isError) {
        when (state.isError) {
            0 -> Toast.makeText(context, savedMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            1 -> Toast.makeText(context, errMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            else -> {}
        }
        onDispose {
            setIsError()
        }
    }
```

**VM**

```
  fun setIsError(){
    _state.update {
        it.copy(
            isError = null,
        )
    }
}
```

So when does on Dispose run for example ?

That's why I used onDisposableEffect here every time the user presses a button, if the operation is successful when the button is pressed, isError 0 comes, if not 1, I want to get a Success message in every successful operation, but once the button is pressed and the operation is successful, the Success message does not work because the key value is isError is still same 0, so I used DisposableEffect to achieve that problem but as I said I don't know the detailed and I did not fully understand

Answer (score 2):

Consider this example code:

```
@Composable
fun example() {
  var inComposition by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
  if (inComposition) {
    DisposableEffect {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

The `DisposableEffect` will leave the composition, and thus run its `onDispose` function, when the `inComposition` variable goes from `true` to `false`.

Comment: can you explain from my code ? when onDispose run in my code ? DisposableEffect run when state.isError become true and it checks whether it is 0 or 1 and outputs a Toast message accordingly and because state.isError comes true again, I need to set it to false so DisposableEffect can work again but in this case when onDispose method run ? I don't understand this . state.isError stays true until onDispose is set to false

Comment: @NewPartizal I'm having a hard time understanding that code. Partially because I'm not sure how `Toast` works (I just do Compose Desktop) and partially because it uses confusing naming (e.g. `setIsError` setting `error` to false).

Comment: sorry for the confusion I updated my code. I hope the code is more clear this time.

Answer (score 0):

`DisposableEffect` is a `remember` function as `LaunchedEffect` difference being it observes remember states while latter comes with a `coroutineScope`.

`dispose` function gets called when the block/Composable `DisposableEffect` leaves composition due to RememberObserver's onForgotten function as below.

This implementation is similar to LaunchedEffect to work only once

```
@Composable
@NonRestartableComposable
fun DisposableEffect(
    key1: Any?,
    effect: DisposableEffectScope.() -> DisposableEffectResult
) {
    remember(key1) { DisposableEffectImpl(effect) }
}
```

LaunchedEffect

```
@Composable
@NonRestartableComposable
@OptIn(InternalComposeApi::class)
fun LaunchedEffect(
    key1: Any?,
    block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit
) {
    val applyContext = currentComposer.applyCoroutineContext
    remember(key1) { LaunchedEffectImpl(applyContext, block) }
}
```

The section how dispose works is

```
private val InternalDisposableEffectScope = DisposableEffectScope()

private class DisposableEffectImpl(
    private val effect: DisposableEffectScope.() -> DisposableEffectResult
) : RememberObserver {
    private var onDispose: DisposableEffectResult? = null

    override fun onRemembered() {
        onDispose = InternalDisposableEffectScope.effect()
    }

    override fun onForgotten() {
        onDispose?.dispose()
        onDispose = null
    }

    override fun onAbandoned() {
        // Nothing to do as [onRemembered] was not called.
    }
}
```

This is basically how lifecycle of remember observation is done.

When you move to a next page, get out of a conditional block or scroll an item out of viewport of LazyColumn/Row onDispose can be used to observe when your block leaves composition.

[Does lazyColumn listen for events when items enter or leave the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73074722/does-lazycolumn-listen-for-events-when-items-enter-or-leave-the-screen)